# After updating Unity, a second EventSystem is created on Run

Tags: unity-game-engine, events, menu

I just updated from Unity **2019.3.13f1** to **2021.3.6f1** mid project. Not ideal I know, but I was advised to by Unity Support in order to add the IAP package. After the update, on running my launch scene, I get this error:

> There are 2 event systems in the scene. Please ensure there is always exactly one event system in the scene

It turns out, a second EventSystem object is being created on running, which hadn't been the case before the update. At first, I just disabled the one in the hierarchy, which solved the problem as the second EventSystem then didn't conflict. However, when the game goes to a second scene and then returns to the initial scene, the duplicate EventSystem is **not** created, meaning that the menus don't get any input!

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Why not just remove the first one and let unity create it on run

Comment: As detailed, it's only added once - and not added when returning to the scene. I've since discovered the reason and patched it - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This forum post (https://forum.unity.com/threads/upgrade-to-2020-lts-creating-duplicate-eventsystem.1098133/) detailed the same problem.

> I have tracked this down to calling Advertisement.Initialize. If I
> call that while running in the Editor; then it creates a new
> EventSystem. I am not sure why. It doesn't seem to matter if I pass
> true or false for the testMode value.

The poster there solved it by surrounding the Initialising line with #if !UNITY_EDITOR. However I wanted to be able to see the adverts testing in the editor - so I added this code, after Advertisement.Initialize(_gameId, _testMode, this):

```
var es = FindObjectsOfType<EventSystem>();
if (es.Length > 1)
{
   for (int i = 1; i < es.Length; i++)
   {
      Destroy(es[i].gameObject);
   }
}
```

This seems to have fixed the problem.